# Алгоритм сохранения любого файла

Tags: php, безопасность

Мне нужно дать пользователю делиться абсолютно любым файлом, при этом при загрузке на сервер использовать минимум проверок.

В голову пока пришло только архивирование файла.

Возможно, ли при загрузке выполнить его архивирование на серверной стороне до сохранения на сервер (до попадания во временную корзину)?

Это с уже существующим файлом. А как сделать с файлом, который пытаются загрузить на сервер до его сохранения?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('path/to/zipfile.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);

$zip->addFile('some-file.pdf', 'subdir/filename.pdf');
$zip->addFile('another-file.xlxs', 'filename.xlxs');

$zip->close();
```

Comment: Да возможно... И возможно ваш вопрос не по теме, сформулируйте его правильно, покажите что вы уже пытались сделать, не делайте рассуждений

Comment: @Walfter я не думаю, что вы располагаете ответом на мой вопрос, но я добавил код, только суть вопроса он не меняет

Comment: До сохранения на сервер файл находится у клиента(без js)

Comment: @Walfter ещё он передается на сервер. Суть вопроса в этом и заключается: формирование архива во время загрузки на сервер или сохранения кода файла в безопасной среде (не файловой)

Comment: Получается до того как файл попадёт на сервер его надо зашифровать и не дать ему исполниться?

Comment: Как мне кажется такого без дополнительного расширения браузера не получится, так как отадётся не сам файл а его байт код(я думаю)

Comment: [PHP file upload and zip on upload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6298286/2881286)